# Package collision matlab2tikz and legend in polaraxis. pgfplotset and multiple size definition problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend, matlab2tikz

How can plots, created by matlab2tikz and common tikzpicture-polaraxis be correctly used within the same document?

The example is of the structure packages, matlab2tikz-pic1, matlab2tikz-pic2 and polaraxis-pic.

The matlab2tikz-pictures are just copy paste. They work well (according to its source) with the following codelines used after \begin{document}

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3,
    every axis legend/.style={
    y tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},                  
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=}}}
    \newlength\figureheight
    \newlength\figurewidth
```

These lines badly affect the legend in polaraxis-pic (frame and alignment).

Putting these lines in the corresponding figure enviorement (after \begin{ figure}) works just for the first time. The second call creates an "already-defined" error message.

Putting one layer deeper into \begin{tikzpicture} causes a hang up of texmaker.

Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                             % Sprache mit Umlauten
\usepackage[{top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=2cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                             % Kodierung
\usepackage{mathcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}                                   % für matlab2tikz
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}                              % für Polarplots
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}                       % für Polarplots
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\xfrac}[2]{%
\mbox{\raisebox{0.6ex}{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #1}}%
{\Large /}%
\raisebox{-0.6ex}{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3,
    every axis legend/.style={
    y tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},                  
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=}}}
    \newlength\figureheight
    \newlength\figurewidth
\begin{center}
\footnotesize
\setlength\figureheight{4cm}
\setlength\figurewidth{8cm} 
% This file was created by matlab2tikz v0.4.2.
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=5,
xlabel={Tiefe [$\mu$m]},
ymin=0,
ymax=105,
ylabel={Temperaturanstieg [K]}
]
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0 98.3383266017213\\
0.6 75.7037719551423\\
1.4 44.0308586761605\\
1.8 31.8836282059977\\
2.6 15.3339893333299\\
3.9 3.79795619734343\\
5 0.987919017813002\\
};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0.5 80.10874197629\\
1 90.10874197629\\
};
\node[above, right, inner sep=0mm, text=black]
at (axis cs:1,90.10874197629,0) {\scriptsize 30 ns, 0 mm};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\hspace{2cm}
\end{center}
\caption{Text}
\end{figure}


%%\begin{figure}[h]
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3,
%   every axis legend/.style={
%   y tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},                  
%   x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=}}}
%    \newlength\figureheight
%    \newlength\figurewidth
%\begin{center}
%\footnotesize
%\setlength\figureheight{4cm}
%\setlength\figurewidth{8cm} 
%% This file was created by matlab2tikz v0.4.2.
%\begin{tikzpicture}
%\begin{axis}[
%width=\figurewidth,
%height=\figureheight,
%scale only axis,
%xmin=0,
%xmax=5,
%xlabel={Tiefe [$\mu$m]},
%ymin=0,
%ymax=105,
%ylabel={Temperaturanstieg [K]}
%]
%\addplot [
%color=black,
%solid,
%forget plot
%]
%table[row sep=crcr]{
%0 98.3383266017213\\
%0.6 75.7037719551423\\
%1.4 44.0308586761605\\
%1.8 31.8836282059977\\
%2.6 15.3339893333299\\
%3.9 3.79795619734343\\
%5 0.987919017813002\\
%};
%\addplot [
%color=black,
%solid,
%forget plot
%]
%table[row sep=crcr]{
%0.5 80.10874197629\\
%1 90.10874197629\\
%};
%\node[above, right, inner sep=0mm, text=black]
%at (axis cs:1,90.10874197629,0) {\scriptsize 30 ns, 0 mm};
%\end{axis}
%\end{tikzpicture}%
%\hspace{2cm}
%\end{center}
%\caption{Text1}
%\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\footnotesize
\begin{tikzpicture}
\definecolor{lgray}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}
\definecolor{dgray}{rgb}{0.3,0.3,0.3}
\makeatletter
\def\pgftransform@angle{0}
\pgfplotsset{
    xticklabel style={
        inner xsep=1pt,
        ellipse,
        anchor=\tick-(180-\pgftransform@angle)
    },
    yticklabel style={
        anchor=90 + \pgftransform@angle
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{polaraxis}[
  rotate=-90,
  xmin=00,
  xmax=90,
  %xtick={0,30,60,90}
  xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,
  xtick={0,15,...,90},
legend style={xshift=3.5cm,yshift=-.2cm}
%legend style={anchor=north west, at={(axis cs:45,4)}}
  ]  
\addplot[red,no markers,smooth] table{
   0 1
   30 2
   60 3
   90 2
    };    
\addlegendentry{Text1}
\addplot[no markers,smooth] table{
   0 2
   30 3
   60 1
   90 1
    };
\addlegendentry{Text2}
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\hspace{2cm}
\end{center}
\caption{Text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding the \pgfplotsset-lines **only** into the first figure environment.

Works but seems not to be good programming. Suggestions are still welcome!

Comment: The problem isn't caused by the `\pgfplotsset` lines, but by the `\newlength` lines. You can only declare lengths once, so all you have to do is remove the second set of `\newlength` statements.